# How to get reassign column values from groupby.aggregrate back to original dataframe in dask?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a dataset like this where each row is player data:

```py
>>> df.head()
```

|  | game_size | match_id | party_size | player_assists | player_kills | player_name | team_id | team_placement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 37 | 2U4GBNA0YmnNZYkzjkfgN4ev-hXSrak_BSey_YEG6kIuDG9fxFrrePqnqiM39pJO | 2 | 0 | 1 | SnuffIes | 4 | 18 |
| 1 | 37 | 2U4GBNA0YmnNZYkzjkfgN4ev-hXSrak_BSey_YEG6kIuDG9fxFrrePqnqiM39pJO | 2 | 0 | 1 | Ozon3r | 4 | 18 |
| 2 | 37 | 2U4GBNA0YmnNZYkzjkfgN4ev-hXSrak_BSey_YEG6kIuDG9fxFrrePqnqiM39pJO | 2 | 0 | 0 | bovize | 5 | 33 |
| 3 | 37 | 2U4GBNA0YmnNZYkzjkfgN4ev-hXSrak_BSey_YEG6kIuDG9fxFrrePqnqiM39pJO | 2 | 0 | 0 | sbahn87 | 5 | 33 |
| 4 | 37 | 2U4GBNA0YmnNZYkzjkfgN4ev-hXSrak_BSey_YEG6kIuDG9fxFrrePqnqiM39pJO | 2 | 0 | 2 | GeminiZZZ | 14 | 11 |

Source: [Full Dataset - Compressed 126MB, Decompressed 1.18GB](https://github.com/OpenDebates/openskill.py/blob/main/benchmark/data/pubg.7z)

I need to create a new column called `weights` where each row is a number between 0 and 1. It needs to be calculated as the total number of kills per player (`player_kills`) divided by the total number of kill per team.

### My Attempt

My initial thought was to create a new column called `total_kills` from a groupby aggregation sum. The it's easy to create the `weights` columns where each row is simply `player_kills` divided by `total_kills`. This is the code so far to calculate the groupby sum.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar

df = dd.read_csv("pubg.csv")
print(df.compute().head().to_markdown())
total_kills = df.groupby(
    ['match_id', 'team_id']
).aggregate({"player_kills": 'sum'}).reset_index()
print(total_kills.compute().head().to_markdown())
```

|  | match_id | team_id | player_kills |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2U4GBNA0YmnNZYkzjkfgN4ev-hXSrak_BSey_YEG6kIuDG9fxFrrePqnqiM39pJO | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 2U4GBNA0YmnNZYkzjkfgN4ev-hXSrak_BSey_YEG6kIuDG9fxFrrePqnqiM39pJO | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 2U4GBNA0YmnNZYkzjkfgN4ev-hXSrak_BSey_YEG6kIuDG9fxFrrePqnqiM39pJO | 14 | 2 |
| 3 | 2U4GBNA0YmnNZYkzjkfgN4ev-hXSrak_BSey_YEG6kIuDG9fxFrrePqnqiM39pJO | 15 | 0 |
| 4 | 2U4GBNA0YmnNZYkzjkfgN4ev-hXSrak_BSey_YEG6kIuDG9fxFrrePqnqiM39pJO | 17 | 1 |

So far, so good. Trying to reassign the new `player_kills` column back using this line of code doesn't work:

```py
df['total_kills'] = total_kills['player_kills']
```

It produces this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\taven\PycharmProjects\openskill.py\benchmark\data\process.py", line 11, in <module>
    df['total_kills'] = total_kills['player_kills']
    ~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\taven\PycharmProjects\openskill.py\benchmark\venv\3.11\Lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 4952, in __setitem__
    df = self.assign(**{key: value})
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\taven\PycharmProjects\openskill.py\benchmark\venv\3.11\Lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 5401, in assign
    data = elemwise(methods.assign, data, *pairs, meta=df2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\taven\PycharmProjects\openskill.py\benchmark\venv\3.11\Lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 6505, in elemwise
    args = _maybe_align_partitions(args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\taven\PycharmProjects\openskill.py\benchmark\venv\3.11\Lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\multi.py", line 176, in _maybe_align_partitions
    dfs2 = iter(align_partitions(*dfs)[0])
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\taven\PycharmProjects\openskill.py\benchmark\venv\3.11\Lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\multi.py", line 130, in align_partitions
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index.
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think dataframes shape are not same,so index issue is existed. You could try these;

```
total_kills = df.groupby(['match_id', 'team_id']).agg(player_total_kills=("player_kills", 'sum')).reset_index()
df_final = pd.merge(left=df,right=total_kills,on=["match_id","team_id"])
```

Btw, i didn't notice its dask question. But logic is same. I think, you need to merge/join dataframes by match_id and team id after aggregation.

I hope it works.